# Firefox needs a plug-in to play online video

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, flash

Whenever I try and play a video of a news event, say by the US President or whatever, Firefox tells me that there is no plug-in.

What does that mean?

Comment: Need to install Flash.

Comment: FIRST PLEASE TURN OFF CAPS LOCK and edit your question. If your caps lock really is broken, please say so.

Answer (score 2):

If you were previously using Internet Explorer, Adobe Flash is only installed as an ActiveX plugin and not the module/add-in version that Firefox requires.

The easiest way to install it is via [Ninite](http://www.ninite.com), simply select `Flash Player for other browsers 10.1.53.64` or you can download it from [Adobe.com by clicking here](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/).